# How to collect data from a camera ICSee

Tags: camera

I have a camera ICSee and I want to build a panel in a web browser to monitoring all of them in different cameras addresses, unfortunately I didn't found any API or guidelines, can you guys help me, can it be any language

I tried to monnitoring the app using charlie debugger proxy to see how the data comes, but not result

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways to do that (I do have ICSEE cam as well). I am not fully aware what camera model do you have, but:

Options:

- install homeassistant and try to integrate camera with it (add ip of the camera, and try to connect using onvif interface
- try to directly access rtsp stream
- try to discover API of the service (if exist) and try to fetch video from there (I am also exploring that -currently no results :) )